# error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type' when transferring pointer

Tags: c, pointers, visual-c++

I am confused by following error when I try to transfer the pointer to another one. Is there anybody can tell me why this error happen?

It says

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
```

when transferring pointer as follow:

```
void compressString(char * pStr)
{
    char * pInputStr ;
    // ...
    pInputStr = pStr;  //**I can not understand why this sentence is error.** 
    // ...
}
```

But this one can work:

```
void compressString(char * pStr)
{
    char * pInputStr = pStr; //No error will be alerted. 
    // ...
}
```

This is more complete version of the function:

```
void compressString(char * pStr)
{

      char * pInputStr = pStr;  
      char * pCompressedStr = NULL;

      int  totalRepeatChar;  
      int currentPointerPosition; 
      int lenCompressedStr = 0;
      char testTemp;
      int i = 0;

      pInputStr = pStr;        //I can not understand why this sentence is error. 

      char arrIntCoverted[DIGITALUINTNUM+1] = {'\0'};

      // And then lots more code in the function
}
```

Comment: Show your complete function body.

Comment: put even some lines before the function in both cases

Comment: Look above the line where error is highlighted. In your case, look at the lines before "pInputStr = pStr;".

Comment: no error in declaration you made some mistake in you code, publish your whole code.

Comment: Hi, I have post my detailed code before the error sentence. To be honest, I can not find any error... But the complier can do it.

Comment: @buildAll: I edited your question and inserted the code that you provided below in an answer, and I also provided an answer explaining the problem. Next time, please provide a _minimal program that still shows the error_ in your question. Don't remove code that you assume is not where the problem is, because often, as in this case, you will remove the actual problem, and then we won't be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

The error you get is because you mix declarations and executable statements, and Visual Studio uses an old C dialect where you can't do that.

This is an executable statement:

```
  pInputStr = pStr;        //I can not understand why this sentence is error.
```

The error you get is not actually on that line, but on the next one, which is a declaration:

```
  char arrIntCoverted[DIGITALUINTNUM+1] = {'\0'};
```

Comment: Yes,you said it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In multiline comments "/" and "*" should be together. In your case you have new line at end of comment.

Check:

```
pInputStr = pStr;  //**I can not understand why this sentence is error.** 
    // ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am afraid, the comment in my question that you indicated is not the original one in my code. The format was changed by stackoverflow when I edited it. You can find the real comment in my code in my latest answer.